# Dolphin reading remote folders is slow

Tags: directory, dolphin, nas

I've mounted several folders from a my NAS and when I try to access them using Dolphin with KDE Plasma 5, it starts to read and try to get the number of elements of each folder.

It takes a lot of time to do that (even, several minutes) because I've got a huge library of files and folders inside.

Is it possible to disable this feature with remote folders or anything to avoid that behaviour?

Thanks!

Edit: I'm using kubuntu 21.10, with KDE plasma 5.22.5.

Comment: Edited. kubuntu 21.10, with KDE plasma 5.22.5.